# How to pass a variable to python script from c++

Tags: python, c++

There are similar questions & answers to this kind of problem but I still can't find a satisfying answer to my specific problem:

I need to pass a variable (should be a global variable to this python script) to a python script from c++ code. I run this python script using following line in c++:

```cpp
PyRun_SimpleString ( "exec(f.read())" );
```

and I want to pass this variable `var="From c++"` to the python environment so code in `f` script is able to access `var` variable.

I'm looking at `PyDict_SetItem` and `PyDict_SetItemString`, etc... but couldn't get it right. How can I do that?

Comment: What about just appending the string `'var="From c++";'` before the `f.read()`?

Comment: @mbostic thank you, I just added a `PyRun_SimpleString("var='From c++' ")` before `f.read()` and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @mbostic 's comment, I did the following and it works:

add this line `PyRun_SimpleString("var='From c++' ");`

before this `PyRun_SimpleString("exec(f.read())");`.

This way `f` is able to access variable `var`.